# Assign values from SQL Server procedure to variable in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, type-conversion

Here is my code in Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC4 using C#

```
int numRows = new SqlCommand("execute getRows", con);
```

Error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to 'int'

Am I missing a step? Like do I have to do an `ExecuteReader()` type of thing?

I can't find a good resource on using SQL commands in ASP.NET MVC 4.

I know NOT to use string concatenation b/c of SQL injection, so I'm trying to use SQL Server stored procedure.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getRows
AS
BEGIN
    select COUNT(*) 
    from myTable 
    where Status = 1
END
```

Note: I have tried casting with `(int)` and with `Int.Parse`. I assume it has something to do with reading it? Or with making getRows procedure have an output?

Comment: ExecuteScalar() will help you in this case.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little more [complicated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

int numRows = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

sqlConnection1.Close();
```

[More](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) information.